# What are ESB test automation specific tools?

Tags: testing, automation, esb

Give some examples for test automation tools used for testing an ESB?
Can Selenium be used for testing or are there any specific tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [Citrus](http://www.citrusframework.org/) is the standard in ESB automation testing.  While I am not as familiar with Selenium, since it is browser automation, at a minimum it can be used for REST based service testing, as this can be done thru a typical browser without additional support.

Google Chrome [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) with jetpack can do both REST and SOAP.